# WebSocket : Connection closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

I have a WebSocket server in an ASP.NET Core C# application.

When the server receives a request it's handled using the following method:

```
private static async Task Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
{
    ArraySegment<Byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new Byte[8192]);
    WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    do
    {
        result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
        ms.Write(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
    }
    while (!result.EndOfMessage);

    string S = ReadMemoryStream(ms);
    // do some stuff

    // Send the response
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Request processed");
    await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes, 0, bytes.Length), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);            
}
```

I'm testing this code from the Console tab in Chrome using JavaScript.

The code works and I'm getting the response "Request processed", but immediately the WS communication is closed and I can't send any other requests.

On the server side, I'm getting the error:

> The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Here is the full stack:

```
 An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (856207216): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake. ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (856207216): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32 minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at WSCommunication.WSComm.Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket) in /home/aspuser/apps/app1/Program/01-WS communication/WSComm.cs:line 88
   at WSCommunication.WSComm.<>c.<<InitializeWS>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in /home/aspuser/apps/app1/Program/01-WS communication/WSComm.cs:line 34
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[2]
      The response has already started, the error page middleware will not be executed.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HM5RCHU6U15R", Request id "0HM5RCHU6U15R:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (856207216): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake. ---> System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (856207216): The remote party closed the WebSocket connection without completing the close handshake.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ThrowIfEOFUnexpected(Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.EnsureBufferContainsAsync(Int32 minimumRequiredBytes, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean throwOnPrematureClosure)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ManagedWebSocket.ReceiveAsyncPrivate[TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter,TWebSocketReceiveResult](Memory`1 payloadBuffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TWebSocketReceiveResultGetter resultGetter)
   at WSCommunication.WSComm.Echo(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket) in /home/aspuser/apps/app1/Program/01-WS communication/WSComm.cs:line 88
   at WSCommunication.WSComm.<>c.<<InitializeWS>b__0_0>d.MoveNext() in /home/aspuser/apps/app1/Program/01-WS communication/WSComm.cs:line 34
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Comment: I think in this case, an [mcve] would include the javascript you're using to connect to the server.

Comment: you have a `WebSocket` referenced elsewhere which makes this issue unable to be solved. We need the whole picture.